# Метод удаления символа JS из массива

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив

```
[
  {  
    "name":"BMW",
    "price":"55 000",
    "color":"red",
    "constructor":"Billy%Zekun"
 },
 {  
   "name":"MERSEDEC",
   "price":"63 000",
   "color":"blue",
   "constructor":"Jon%Adams"
 }
];
```

Какой Метод использовать что бы выводилось :

```
"constructor":"Jon Adams"
```

то есть удалялся символ % и заменялся на пробел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr = [
  {

    "name":"BMW",
    "price":"55 000",
    "color":"red",
    "constructor":"Billy%Zekun"
 },
 {

   "name":"MERSEDEC",
   "price":"63 000",
   "color":"blue",
   "constructor":"Jon%Adams"
 }
];

for(let item of arr) {
  item.constructor = item.constructor.replace(/%/g, ' ');
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте метод `replace` (подробнее т[ут](https://javascript.ru/string/replace)).

```
str.replace('%', ' ');
```